# Using Javascript Action on Onload event

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload

I'm new to javascript and can't change my code to what I wanted.

```
<iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe"
style="display:none;" onload="if(submitted)
{window.location='http://site.html';}"></iframe>
```

My intention is use this window.location (redirecting to other page) to start an action in the same page. If it was a link, my code would be:

```
<a onClick="OpenSel(1)"></a>
```

How can I use OpenSel(1) after the onload event?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stick it after what's already in there:

```
onload="if (submitted) {window.location='http://site.html';} OpenSel(1)"
```

Although it's probably easier if you stick this all in a function:

```
function loadCheck() {
    if (submitted) {
        window.location='http://site.html';
    } 
    OpenSel(1)
}

onload="loadCheck()"
```

Comment: Oh, God. THANK YOU tymeJV!! Just what I wanted!